# DOMPDF file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s):

Tags: php, dompdf

I succeeded in getting DOMPDF to work perfectly but I cant seem to get rid of the following error in my PHP error.log.

```
[17-Sep-2015 16:12:01 Europe/Brussels] PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/lib/fonts/Helvetica-Bold.ttf) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/data2inf/:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/data2inf/public_html/_test/biqsdrive/dompdf/lib/class.pdf.php on line 2237
```

I can't find a working solution for my problem.

Comment: move the file to somewhere you're allowed to access it, or turn off open_basedir.

Comment: The message is clear, you should move font file to a non-restricted place.